# Make a color stay on CSS element when selected

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Trying to find a way to make a CSS element stay the same color that is set on hover when the element is selected. This is for size variations on a WooCommerce site.

My CSS Code is:

```
.va-picker-item:hover {
background-color: #000;
}

.va-picker-item:focus {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

which works fine.

The HTML is:

```
    <div class="va-separator clear"></div>
    <label class="va-attribute-label">Size</label>
    <div class="va-pickers">
        <a class="va-picker va-picker-text " data-attribute="pa_size" data-term="small" title="Small" ><span class="va-picker-item va-text S" >S</span></a>
        <a class="va-picker va-picker-text " data-attribute="pa_size" data-term="medium" title="Medium" ><span class="va-picker-item va-text M" >M</span></a>
        <a class="va-picker va-picker-text " data-attribute="pa_size" data-term="large" title="Large" ><span class="va-picker-item va-text L" >L</span></a>
    </div>
    <!-- /.va-pickers -->
    <div class="va-separator clear"></div>
</div><!-- /.ql-visual-variations -->
```

I've tried variations of :selected etc but to no avail. Any ideas? I understand that jQuery may also be an option, but my Javascript knowledge is practically nonexistent and the plugin developer offers no support on customization.

Comment: Did you try :active?

Comment: Normaly, after you change the page the active menu gets an active class..
check if there is one and use it

Comment: Yes, I've tried :active. So the element changes when clicked. I just need the element to continue displaying that way until another item is selected.

Comment: So now we have `.va-picker-item:hover {
 background-color: #000;
}

.va-picker-item:focus {
 background-color: #FFF;
}

.va-picker-item:active {
 background-color: #FFF;
 color: red;
}`

Comment: Have you checked the HTML of a selected element? Perhaps Woo Commerce adds a class to it that you could use to target it in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add href attribute to your html link element so you can use :focus pseudo selector

**HTML**

```
 <div class="va-separator clear"></div>
    <label class="va-attribute-label">Size</label>
    <div class="va-pickers">
        <a href="#" class="va-picker va-picker-text " data-attribute="pa_size" data-term="small" title="Small" ><span class="va-picker-item va-text S" >S</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="va-picker va-picker-text " data-attribute="pa_size" data-term="medium" title="Medium" ><span class="va-picker-item va-text M" >M</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="va-picker va-picker-text " data-attribute="pa_size" data-term="large" title="Large" ><span class="va-picker-item va-text L" >L</span></a>
    </div>
    <!-- /.va-pickers -->
    <div class="va-separator clear"></div>
</div><!-- /.ql-visual-variations -->
```

**CSS**

```
.va-pickers a {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.va-pickers a:focus {
  color: red;
}
.va-pickers a:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

**DEMO** -> https://jsfiddle.net/8d483ze4/

**OR** Better use jQuery -> https://jsfiddle.net/8d483ze4/1/

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that a class was indeed added to the element when it was selected, making it easy to target. Thanks everyone for your helpful advice.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution. Just use this jQuery and update your css as below:

jQuery

```
$('.va-pickers .va-picker').click(function(){
    $('.va-pickers .va-picker').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
})
```

CSS

```
.va-pickers .va-picker.selected{
   background:black;
   color:white;
}
```

Check my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/7wdkrurf/) demo.